# Inserting data into third table in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

```
Category                    Subcategory                    Mapping
  id                           id                          Category_id
  name                         name                        Sub_Category_id
```

I have created models and controllers for category and subcategory .
How to insert data into the third table "Mapping" whenever I am adding new subcategory??

SubCategory form is having 3 fields.

1.DropDownList Category_Name
2.TextField Sub Category Name
3.Auto Generated Id of Subcategory

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: I have not tried bcoz I don't kmow how do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a problem, maybe you could share what you have tried.
It should basically work like this (not tested)

```
class Subcategory{

  ...

protected function afterSave() {
    parent::afterSave();
    if ($this->isNewRecord) {
     $map = new Mapping();
     $map->Category_Id = $this->parentCategory->id;
     $map->Sub_Category_Id = $this->id;
     $map->save();
    }
}
...

}
```

this is assuming that you have a relation from `Subcategory` to `Category` called `parentCategory`

Comment: Yup. That is the method I use.

Comment: ok thanks ..I just wanted know that whether it was necessary to create model and controller for mapping or not. got my answer..thanks